# Aggregation on multiple columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

### Data:

```
z = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'b':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'c':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})
```

### My code:

```
gbz = z.groupby('a')
f1 = lambda x: x.loc[x['b'] > 4]['c'].mean()
f2 = lambda x: x.mean()
f3 = {'I don't know what should I write here':{'name1':f1}, 'b':{'name2': f2}}
list1 = gbz.agg(f3)
```

### Question:

How can I put more than one column to use in function "f1" ? (This function needs two columns of the groupby object)

### Expected result:

```
     name1  name2
1    12.0   4
2    13.5   6.5
3    15.5   8.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested dictionary in `agg` function is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming). What you might do is use `groupby.apply` and return a properly indexed series for each group for renaming purpose:

```
(z.groupby('a')
  .apply(lambda g: pd.Series({
    'name1': g.c[g.b > 4].mean(),
    'name2': g.b.mean()
})))

#  name1    name2
#a      
#1  12.0    4.0
#2  13.5    6.5
#3  15.5    8.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `agg` with a `lambda` like this:

```
g = z.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: [x[(x.b > 4)].c.mean(), x.b.mean()])
```

You'll have to rename your columns manually:

```
g.columns = ['name1', 'name2']
```

---

```
print(g)
   name1  name2
a              
1   12.0    4.0
2   13.5    6.5
3   15.5    8.5
```